# ASP.NET Can I make a custom attribute to deal with authorizing scopes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, annotations

Sorry if this is very basic but I've never done something like this before.

In my app, we're using Azure AD B2C to take care of our users. When using an endpoint, we require a JWT token that contains a scope, say "TestScope" for now. Currently I have this code that works:

```
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        // The web API will only accept tokens 1) for users, and 2) having the "TestScope" scope for this API
        static readonly string[] scopeRequiredByApi = new string[] { "TestScope" };

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(scopeRequiredByApi);

            return "test";
        }
    }
```

My idea was that instead of using those two lines of code every time I make an endpoint, could I possibly make a custom attribute, like '[Authorise(Scope = "TestScope")]' to do the same thing? Or maybe a '[TestScope]' tag where I don't have to write the string and potentially make a spelling mistake, though I guess that would be pretty obvious quickly if I did.

Thanks for any advice! Appreciate it

Comment: I think if you're using Microsoft.Identity.Web you should be able to use something like: [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "TestScope" })]

Answer (score 0):

Just think out loud here, it depends how often you want to do the check and this is how I will probably approach it.

1. If it is one off or maybe few calls you can go with Enums to avoid spelling
   mistakes.
2. If you want to check every now and then maybe custom attribute/action
   filter can be a good choice.
3. If its part of authorization check after user has logged in and authorized
   can be used with authorization filter with custom attribute to ignore when
   required.
4. If you want to check on every request authorized/unauthorized you can look
   at making custom middleware.